# How do I use conventions to conditionally bind an interface to a type depending on what it's injected into?

Tags: c#, ninject

I have a number of types with constructors taking an `ICommand` parameter, like this:

```
public AboutCommandMenuItem(ICommand command)
    : base(command)
{
}
```

```
public OptionsCommandMenuItem(ICommand command) 
    : base(command)
{
}
```

I'm using Ninject and I have the `ICommand` interface configured like this:

```
_kernel.Bind<ICommand>().To<AboutCommand>().WhenInjectedExactlyInto<AboutCommandMenuItem>();
_kernel.Bind<ICommand>().To<OptionsCommand>().WhenInjectedExactlyInto<OptionsCommandMenuItem>();
```

Is there a way to set up a convention so that I could bind the `ICommand` interface to `XxxxCommand` when it's injected into `XxxxCommandMenuItem`, and avoid having to manually configure every possible type the interface can be injected into?

I tried `BindToSelection` but the selector expression doesn't capture the type I'm injecting into, and `BindToRegex` seems to be nothing more than a stringly-typed selector.

This is the closest I could get:

```
_kernel.Bind(t => t.FromThisAssembly()
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .InNamespaceOf<ICommand>()
    .EndingWith("Command")
    .Where(type => type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICommand)))
    .BindAllInterfaces()
    .Configure(binding => binding
        .When(request => request.Service == typeof(ICommand) 
                      && request.Target.Member.DeclaringType.Name.StartsWith(?)));
```

Where `?` would be the name of the class that's selected for binding.

Am I stuck with explicit bindings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Precursor:
Depending on other constraints, it might be better to adapt the design as to not share the `ICommand` interface. Why? It will never ever make sense to inject an `OptionsCommand` into the `AboutCommandMenuItem`. But the ctor of `AboutCommandMenuItem` makes it look as if it would be ok.

However, I'm going to assume you still want to go forward with this. Here are several possible solutions to your problem (which don't affect your design choice):

- [Named Bindings](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding#simple-constrained-resolution-named-bindings). You can use a convention with a [IBindingGenerator](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/BindingGenerators/IBindingGenerator.cs) to create the binding
- The approach with a `When` condition that you already found. Again, combine it with a [IBindingGenerator](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/BindingGenerators/IBindingGenerator.cs)

  - Alternative a) the condition check the name or type. The matching type is computed as part of the `When` expression execution
  - Alternative b) the binding generator computes the matching type and the `When` expression only performs the comparison.

Exemplar implementation for the last option / alternative:

### The Codez

(interesting parts first)

The test (demonstrating ItWorxxTm)

```
using FluentAssertions;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions;
using Xunit;

public class MenuItemCommandConventionTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind(x => x
            .FromThisAssembly()
            .IncludingNonePublicTypes()
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .InheritedFrom<ICommand>()
            .BindWith<CommandBindingGenerator>());

        kernel.Get<AboutMenuItem>()
              .Command.Should().BeOfType<AboutCommand>();
        kernel.Get<OptionsMenuItem>()
              .Command.Should().BeOfType<OptionsCommand>();
    }
}
```

Binding Generator:

```
using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.BindingGenerators;
using Ninject.Syntax;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public class CommandBindingGenerator : IBindingGenerator
{
    private const string CommandSuffix = "Command";
    private const string MenuItemTypeNamePattern = "{0}MenuItem";

    public IEnumerable<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>> CreateBindings(
        Type type, IBindingRoot bindingRoot)
    {
        string commandName = GetCommandName(type);

        Type menuItem = FindMatchingMenuItem(type.Assembly, commandName);

        var binding = bindingRoot.Bind(typeof(ICommand)).To(type);

        // this is a slight hack due to the return type limitation
        // but it works as longs as you dont do Configure(x => .When..)
        binding.WhenInjectedInto(menuItem); 
        yield return binding;
    }

    private static Type FindMatchingMenuItem(
        Assembly assembly, string commandName)
    {
        string expectedMenuItemTypeName = string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
            MenuItemTypeNamePattern,
            commandName);

        Type menuItemType = assembly.GetTypes()
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == expectedMenuItemTypeName);

        if (menuItemType == null)
        {
            string message = string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "There's no type named '{0}' in assembly {1}",
                expectedMenuItemTypeName,
                assembly.FullName);
            throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
        }

        return menuItemType;
    }

    private static string GetCommandName(Type type)
    {
        if (!type.Name.EndsWith(CommandSuffix))
        {
            string message = string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "the command '{0}' does not end with '{1}'",
                type.FullName,
                CommandSuffix);
            throw new ArgumentException(message);
        }

        return type.Name.Substring(
            0,
            type.Name.Length - CommandSuffix.Length);
    }
}
```

The commands and menu items:

```
public interface ICommand
{ 
}

class AboutCommand : ICommand
{
}

internal class OptionsCommand : ICommand
{
}

public abstract class MenuItem
{
    private readonly ICommand command;

    protected MenuItem(ICommand command)
    {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return this.command; }
    }
}

public class OptionsMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    public OptionsMenuItem(ICommand command)
        : base(command) { }
}

public class AboutMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    public AboutMenuItem(ICommand command)
        : base(command) { }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. That's what I get for writing code at 4AM... I suggest you take a look at the [full context of the code](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/98979/23788) and score some more rep there with an answer based on your first paragraph. Anyway this is a very educative answer here, thanks!

Comment: Note, the reason for registering `ICommand` is so each command's dependencies can be resolved automagically.  The "About" dialog doesn't do much, but something like a "RefactorExtractMethodCommand" would be much less trivial.